# Cannot get OSM tags when downloading data with osmnx functions which are based on Nominatim requests

Tags: python, openstreetmap, overpass-api, nominatim, osmnx

## Context

I am trying to download some footway graph from [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/) (OSM) using [osmnx](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Here is a piece of code:

```
import os, sys
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import matplotlib.colors as colors
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox
ox.config(log_console=True, use_cache=True)
ox.__version__

G_test = ox.osm_net_download(polygon=None,
                             north=46.95489, west=7.46006,
                             south=46.95335, east=7.46132,
                             network_type='walk'
                             )
```

The [`ox.osm_net_download()`](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.core.osm_net_download) method, is based on the Overpass API, so if I check what's in `G_test` and search for this OSM way `295557051` I can see that the OSM tags are shipped with the data:

```
{'type': 'way',
    'id': 295557051,
    'nodes': [2992861879,
     2992861880,
     (...) # bunch of vertex coordinates here, skipped for clarity
     2992864399],
    'tags': {'footway': 'sidewalk', 'highway': 'footway', 'surface': 'paved'}
}
```

The `tags` are of course the same as the one found by making a direct call to the [Overpass API](https://overpass-turbo.eu/#) or the OSM API (on which the previous seems to rely) at this address for this way:
https://www.openstreetmap.org/way/295557051

Up to this point, everything is fine.
But the [`ox.osm_net_download()`](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.core.osm_net_download) method doesn't return a [networkx](https://networkx.github.io/) [graph object](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/index.html), it returns a Python [list](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html).

Therefore, to download a graph, I usually query the data through any of the proposed `graph_from_*()` methods, for example a [`graph_from_bbox*()`](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.core.graph_from_bbox) as:

```
G = ox.graph_from_bbox(north=46.95490, west=7.46000,
                       south=46.95330, east=7.46230,
                       network_type='walk',
                       retain_all=True)
```

## Issue

But when downloading the data using the latter method, the OSM tags no longer come with the data!
This is probably due the fact that the `graph_from_*()` methods are not based on the Overpass API but rather on the Nominatim API.
This may be related to: [Cannot get response from nominatim API on some OSM objects](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/353225/cannot-get-response-from-nominatim-api-on-some-osm-objects)

If I explore the result of the `G` graph, searching for the OSM way `295557051`:

```
G_raw.edges(keys=True, data=True)
```

One of the may results (as they are many edges composing this OSM feature) look like this:

```
(2992861879, 2992861880, 0, {'osmid': 295557051, 'highway': 'footway', 'oneway': False, 'length': 4.821}),
```

For a better comprehension, we can convert it to a [GeoDataFrame](https://geopandas.org/reference/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.html) using the [`ox.graph_to_gdfs()`](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.save_load.graph_to_gdfs) method:

```
G_gdf = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, 
                         nodes=True, 
                         edges=True, 
                         node_geometry=True, 
                         fill_edge_geometry=True)
```

And print its content:

```
G_gdf[1][G_gdf[1]['osmid']==295557051]
```

[image: GDF from osmnx graph]
(OSM tags are not there.)

This problem is also propagated when saving the graph to an [ESRI Shapefile](https://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf) using [`ox.save_graph_shapefile()`](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.save_load.save_graph_shapefile):

```
ox.save_graph_shapefile(G, filename=os.path.join('~/test_graph'))
```

Indeed, when I open the resulting Shapefile, for example in [QGIS](https://www.qgis.org), a query on that same way doesn't show the OSM tags in the attribute table.

[image: QGIS screenshot]

## Question

I wonder where the tags are lost in the process and how to solve for this issue?

#### Note:

I was first thinking of converting the `G` graph to a GeoDataFrame, merging it with `G_test` which I also convert to a GeoDataFrame and then convert back that merged GeoDataFrame to a networkX graph, but I went into a strange error because the retrieved graph doesn't have the right structure:

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Or to directly write the GeoDataFrame to PostGIS:

```
AttributeError: 'GeometryDtype' object has no attribute 'base'
```

But GeoPandas doesn't handle (yet) writing data to PostGIS:
https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/pull/1248

So I'm stuck.

Comment: I'm not familiar with osmnx but I doubt that `graph_from_*()` methods call Nominatim and not Overpass. Nominatim is not suited for obtaining data for a specific bounding box since it is mainly a geocoder. So I guess there must be something else which removes tags after downloading.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar problem, I wanted to access the **surface** of streets.

### Answer

The setting of the attributes that are transferred to the graph are defined in the [settings.py](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/blob/15eddc0672f0ec951ada1b89eb417df44d35636e/osmnx/settings.py#L31-L33)

```
useful_tags_path = ['bridge', 'tunnel', 'oneway', 'lanes', 'ref', 'name',
                    'highway', 'maxspeed', 'service', 'access', 'area',
                    'landuse', 'width', 'est_width', 'junction']
```

You can edit the settings with `ox.utils.config()`. I added **surface** to the list of useful tags. This did the trick.

```
import osmnx as ox
useful_tags_path = ['bridge', 'tunnel', 'oneway', 'lanes', 'ref', 'name',
                    'highway', 'maxspeed', 'service', 'access', 'area',
                    'landuse', 'width', 'est_width', 'junction', 'surface']
ox.utils.config(useful_tags_path=useful_tags_path)
```

```
 (3339714877,
  1395396060,
  {'osmid': 527255117,
   'highway': 'path',
   'surface': 'grass',
   'oneway': False,
   'length': 361.7989999999999,
   'geometry': <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x7fe6d9972490>})
```

I hope this helps you!

### EDIT:

You can also manually set the following parameter with a list containing the tags you want:

```
ox.settings.useful_tags_path = ['surface', 'witdth', 'lanes', ...]
```

Source: https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#module-osmnx.utils

Comment: Oops, I totally forgot to come back here to post the solution I actually found a few days ago. And indeed, it was the same than the one you posted. But in my case, I have set up the tags I wanted as `ox.settings.useful_tags_path = [ list of tags ]`.

Comment: For anyone else who comes along here, note that the old `useful_tags_path` setting was deprecated and [replaced](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.utils.config) by the new `useful_tags_way` setting in a recent release. Same functionality.